# Promise array and scoping trouble while using exceljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, exceljs

So I have been fighting with my Nodejs app to figure out how to build an array of promise reliably. I have read multiple duplicate questions but I can't seem to figure out why its going wrong in my case. Something I realize is the fact that there is something wrong with the scoping of my variables.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

module.exports = async function (worksheet) {
   var promises = [];
   worksheet.eachRow(async function (row, rowNum) {
      if( //some condition met ) {
         
          // stuff gets done -------

         const writeFilePromisified = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);

         const doSomethingAsync = async () => {
            await writeFilePromisified(`file.pdf`, pdfBytes);
            console.log('file write done with promisified writeFile');
         }
      let pro = doSomethingAsync();
      promises.push(pro);
      }
   }
   Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
      console.log("Done");
   });
}
```

As I understood, this should have waited for all promises to be resolved and then log "Done".
But this just doesn't wait for promises and sees `undefined` and logs `Done` immediately.

So anyone can help me figure out why this is happening? Because if I log `promises` inside the `worksheet.eachRow` function, I am able to see all the `pending promises`. But the moment I step out of that function, everything disappears.

## Solution derived from @hellikiam's answer:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

const rows = worksheet.getRows(<contentStart>, worksheet.rowCount);  // check and verify row count for your excelsheet

module.exports = async function (worksheet) {
   var promises = rows.map(async function (row, index) {
      try{
         if( //some condition met ) {
         
             // stuff gets done -------

            const doSomethingAsync = async () => {
               const res = await writeFile(`file.pdf`, pdfBytes, (_) => "Done");
               return res;
            }
            let pro = await doSomethingAsync();
            return pro;
         }
      } catch (e => throw e);
   }
   await Promise.all(promises)
   console.log("Done");
}
```

His answer was having promise anti-pattern because we are already in async function and we can return a value and it automatically returns a promise along with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is about callback timing issue in javascript. Javascript will push your callback into schedule queue and stack will be executed after wrapper function is done.

so that, the callback of `worksheet.eachRow(cb)` will be executed after `Promise.all(promises)`. To synchronize this process, you'd better using synchonous function like `Array.prototype.map`.

Try this way, I added some async/await and functional way to keep it reliable.

```
module.exports = async function (worksheet) {
   var promises = worksheet.rows.map(function (row, rowNum) {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>{
        try{
           if( //some condition met ) {
          // stuff gets done -------

         const writeFilePromisified = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);

         const doSomethingAsync = async () => {
            await writeFilePromisified(`file.pdf`, pdfBytes);
            console.log('file write done with promisified writeFile');
         }
         let pro = await doSomethingAsync();
         return resolve(pro);
      }
        }
        catch(e){
          return reject(e)
        }
      })
   }
   
   const values = await Promise.all(promises)
   console.log(values)
   console.log('Done')
}
```

Comment: Yea, the main problem seems to be .eachRow(cb) function because it is designed to not return any promise. It remains undefined so I could not attach any promise to it and was looking for workarounds. Let me see if your snippet works for me.

Comment: Nope, `worksheet.row.map` is not valid function and if I try to do the same with `eachRow` in place of map, I get the error `undefined is not iterable`.

Comment: Well... That was an pseudo code to explain how it works. You should get row instances from exceljs before do something with it.

I didn't know about the module you used so I searched it behalf of you.

Worksheet instance has rowCount property and getRow(startIndex, retrievingCount) interface. I think you can get the row instances by use those lik worksheet.getRow(0, worksheet.rowCount) which seems like to be iterable instance(Array).

check out the official reference (https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#rows)

Comment: I figured it was a pseudo code for it was worth a try haha. But yea, that's what I am doing right now actually. I did not want to go this route originally, but looks like eachRow isn't doing the job here, so I will just have to map the rows myself. Will comment again as soon as I am done.

Comment: @ark_knight Happy hacking brother!

Comment: Smh. Well good new first. The promises are stacking up in array. Bad news, the program finishes execution before promises can resolve. That means, its not waiting for pending to change to resolved. Tried writing resolve inside the `doSomethingAsync( )` (because at least `console.log` inside that function waits for the file writing to finish), but no luck there either.

Comment: Ayo, figured it out. We were trying to do something called Promise anti-pattern. Seems like that was confusing Node and it finished the execution with no callback lined up. I will update my question with proper answer and mark yours as solution too! Thanks for bearing with me haha!

Comment: @ark_knight Yup I'm expecting for you to share your solution soon enough. Good luck with that!